# How to avoid footwear wear and tear?

Tags: footwear

My shoes break frequently and easily:

Broken heels:

> [image]

Broken soles:

> [image]

Is there any way to avoid these different types of wear and tear? Is there a way to increase durability of footwear?

I've tried insoles and different types of tapes - but they all seem to slightly delay issues rather than actually fixing anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Apart from the footwear quality itself, it may have something to do with the *way* you walk. If you drag the soles and/or heels they will wear must faster than if your walking style is to "pick up your feet", so that there is minimal scraping on the ground. See [How can a walking style be changed?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/how-can-a-walking-style-be-changed) It is possible to change your walking style - I know because I did so after I damaged one foot.

Comment: Can you comment -- in the question -- if they are relatively cheap shoes or not?

Comment: shoes, like everything else, get worn when you use them, so wear and tear is inevitable. Many shoes can be re-soled, talk to your local cobbler, or to the manufacturer of your shoes.

Comment: It usually takes me about 6 months of general use in the city to wreck a pair of shoes like that. Hard surfaces destroy the soft rubber soles.

Comment: @WeatherVane unless a walking style is causing physical issues like pain or excessive local fatigue, I'd be wary of trying to force something different.  That's not to say never do it, but do it with care and thought

Comment: If you keep the boots in a store room near to cleaning chemicals, the rubber can degrade quite quickly.

Answer (score 5):

**Good quality shoes**

Good quality shoes will hold long. My trekking shoes with Vibram soles are in a very good state after about 5000 km. Much cheaper (but also lighter) Decathlon shoes can hold about 1000-1500km before they start to soak because of tear (nevertheless, the soles are still in acceptable condition.

Cheap shoes from bazaar are cheap because they're made of poor quality material. Poor quality rubber will tear and break very fast.

Shoes and weatherproof jacket are the only parts of hiking equipment you shouldn't save on. Everything else can be a cheap crap and still hold for years.

Comment: (A cheap pack may cause way more effort than it is worth, what with being uncomfortable or having straps fail on the trail.)

Comment: (I was let down by a cheap tent on the very first night).

Comment: [*insert Sam Vimes quote on boots here*]

Comment: and the extremely timely and relevant "Vimes Boot Index": https://www.theguardian.com/books/2022/jan/26/terry-pratchett-jack-monroe-vimes-boots-poverty-index

Comment: Note that the distance you get out of soles will depend a lot on the surface on which you are trekking.  I've had Vibram soles last over 5000 km and I've also worn through them in less than 1000 km.  I personally buy boots that can be resoled.  I have one pair that is on their 6th pair of soles.  I'm not sure my orthopaedist agrees it's a good idea to use boots for so long, but they sure are comfy and I know exactly what to expect out of them.

Comment: I had a pair of boots with a vibram sole that failed me after a handful of days. This was a well known Italian brand starting with L...

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket similarly I had some approach shoes that I wore for work somewhere casual.  1000km of urban walking finished them off.  I've just repaired some ankle boots that are otherwise identical where the sole came unglued.  They lasted 10 years but I don't know how far I walked in them. Now they're relegated to light duty

Comment: @Manziel In what way did they fail?  Was it the sole that failed or something else?

Comment: The sole was showing excessive wear near the tip. And by excessive I mean that I could literally watch that sole wear out. I have not seen such a wear on any other boot happen in years that happened within days. I feel lucky that I made it back to civilization before the sole was completely through. To add insult to injury, customer support refused to accept that this boot had a sole with a manufacturing defect (I cannot explain this by any other reason).

Comment: Asking what, "Good quality shoes," are on Outdoors @ SE would be off-topic, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

**How to avoid footwear wear and tear?**

For what it is worth, you would do good as previously recommended to wear **good quality shoes**.

Something else I suspect plays a part in all this is the amount of time the particular pair of shoes have been on the shelf so to speak before someone has purchased the shoes in question. Look for the manufacturing date before buying them.

I can buy a pair shoes at one store for about the third the price of the same shoes at other stores. But what I have notice by personal experience, is that the shoes deteriorated rather quickly.

Personally it pays to obtain shoes where the turnover is more common. Shoes will normally have been manufactured more recently. Some stores I now avoid if I want good manufactured shoes.

With all said and done there is no one perfect answer to your question.

The average person can not alter the way they walk, without much training, but we can treat our shoes in order to avoid some wear and tear, but not all.

Comment: It is not true that we cannot alter the way we walk. We *can* learn to alter or improve our gait. Look how military training can convert the bearing and walking style of its recruits. From say, a despondent shuffle to a purposeful clean stride.

Comment: Asking what, "Good quality shoes," are on Outdoors @ SE would be off-topic, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Mou某 Asking for brands or models certainly, yes. But one could ask more generally for the advantages of certain aspects for specific tasks (leather/synthetic, light/heavy, low ancle/boot, ... for trecking, mountaineering, long-distance hiking etc.) I'd not be surprised if a question in that direction already exists, though.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience walking on concrete, asphalt roads destroys the soles the most. That and combo of draggin them. I mostly do longer hikes and I have to use concrete, asphalt roads from time to time between locations.
If you accidently drag the sole on such a hard surface, the profile wears much faster. In my opinion you shouldnt wait to get such tear as in first photos. Less profile means less traction and could be dangerous. Shoes with less profile also mean less walking confort, feet will probably hurt even more.